# Can the bonus action Two-Weapon Fighting be used with a hand crossbow after making an unarmed attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, unarmed-combat, two-weapon-fighting

I've started a Blood Hunter at level 3 and am using unarmed attacks.  Since I'm not holding a weapon in my hand, could I strike with an unarmed attack, then use a hand crossbow in the other hand to make the attack?  It would look like this:

1. Punch
2. Load weapon (part of the Ammunition trait)
3. Fire hand crossbow

Can the bonus action Two-Weapon Fighting be used with a hand crossbow after making an unarmed attack in this manner?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## You cannot TWF unarmed or with a crossbow.

[Two Weapon Fighting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#TwoWeaponFighting)

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a **light melee weapon** that you're holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different **light melee weapon** that you're holding in the other hand. You don't add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative.

Unarmed strikes are not made with weapons, and certainly not light weapons.

Ranged attacks made with hand crossbows are not melee.

You could however use the [Crossbow Expert](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crossbow-expert) feat when attacking with a weapon:

> When you use the Attack action and attack with a one handed weapon, you can use a bonus action to attack with a hand crossbow you are holding.